# A sequence of compact operators, weak convergence versus strong convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

We consider two sequences of bounded linear operators $\{T_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{S_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$  on $L^2(X,\mu)$. We denote by $\mathcal{L}$ the space of bounded linear operators on $L^2(X,\mu)$.
We assume that $\{T_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ strongly converges to some $T \in \mathcal{L}$, and $\{S_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ weakly converges to $S \in \mathcal{L}$. Then, it is easy to show that $\{T_nS_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ weakly converges to $TS$ in $L^2(X,\mu)$.

In general, $\{T_nS_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge to $TS$ strongly in $L^2(X,\mu)$.

Then, we assume that each $T_n$ possesses a non-negative integral kernel. That is, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $p_n=p_n(x,y)\colon X \times X \to [0,\infty)$ such that
\begin{align*}
T_nf(x)=\int_{X}p_n(x,y)f(y)\,\mu(dy),\quad f \in L^2(X,\mu),\quad \mu\text{-a.e. }x\in X.
\end{align*}
We assume moreover that there exists $C>0$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{align*}
(1)\quad\mu\text{-ess.sup}_{x,y \in X}\,p_n(x,y) \in [0,C).
\end{align*}
Then, each $T_n$ is of Hilbert--Schmidt type (in particular, $T_n$ is a compact  operator  on $L^2(X,\mu)$). Also, in this situation, $\{T_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is expected to have better properties.

> **Question.** If $u \in L^2(X,\mu)$ is bounded  and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|S_nu|$ is
> a bounded function, can we show that
> \begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{X}|T_nS_n u-TSu|^2\,d\mu=0 \,?
> \end{align*}

**ADD:** It may be natural to see that $\{S_nu\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is injected to a some  compact  space by $\{T_n\}_{n=1}^\infty.$ In this sense, we might have to discuss a subsequence of $\{T_nS_n u\}$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused (but most likely I'm just misunderstanding something): Your question is wether $T_nS_nu$ converges in norm to $TSu$; but in your last sentence you say that you already know that $T_nS_nu$ converges to $TSu$. What am I missing?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Sorry. The contents of this question was changed without my knowing. I modified it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! One more question: Do you also assume a lower bound on the orbit of $u$ under $(S_n)$, for instance that $\inf_n S_n u$ is also a bounded function?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes. I assume that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|S_nu|$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!. I first expected that this should be true, but I experienced some difficulties in the proof. I'll think about it in more detail; in case that I find out something, I'll let you know.

Comment: @JochenGlueck  I also think this should valid. If $T$ is compact and satisfies the same condition as (1), I wonder if it can be shown more easily. Anyway, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Actually, it follows from your assumptions that $T$ is also a compact integral operator, and its integral kernel p indeed satisfies (1). The only problem in the proof is to show that the integral operators with kernels $|p_n - p|$ - let's call them $R_n$ - do converge strongly to $0$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Ah. I see.